# Cannot insert the value NULL into column '', table column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_LMS_dealerorusercreation_IUDS]
@dealrid bigint,
@rid bigint,
@stateid bigint,
@regonid bigint,
@Locid bigint,
@pid varchar(MAX),
@address varchar(max),
@dealrname varchar(25),
@landno bigint,
@mobno bigint,
@altcontno bigint,
@email varchar(35),
@desig varchar(25),
@reporting varchar(30),
@status int,
@action varchar(10),
@CompanyId Uniqueidentifier

AS
DECLARE @TranStatus VARCHAR(5)
 BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
      IF(@action='Insert')
         BEGIN
          INSERT INTO LMS_dealerorusercreation(
rid,
stateid,
regonid,
Locid,
addres,
dealrname,
landno,
mobno,
altcontno,
email,
desig,
reporting,
status,
CompanyId
)
VALUES(
@rid,
@stateid,
@regonid,
@Locid,
@address,
@dealrname,
@landno,
@mobno,
@altcontno,
@email,
@desig,
@reporting,
@status,
@CompanyId
)
SELECT @dealrid = dealrid FROM LMS_dealerorusercreation WHERE mobno = @mobno AND email = @email
EXEC [dbo].[SP_LMS_SetDealerProductMapping]
@dealerId = @dealrid,
@prodid = @pid
SET @TranStatus='TRUE';
END       

IF(@action='Update')
     BEGIN
    UPDATE LMS_dealerorusercreation set rid= @rid,
    stateid=@stateid,
    regonid=@regonid,
    Locid=@Locid,
    addres=@address,
    dealrname=@dealrname,
    landno=@landno,
    mobno=@mobno,
    altcontno=@altcontno,
    email=@email,
    desig=@desig,
    reporting=@reporting,
    status=@status
    WHERE dealrid=@dealrid

SET @TranStatus='TRUE';       
    END              
    IF(@action='Delete')
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM LMS_dealerorusercreation WHERE dealrid=@dealrid
    SET @TranStatus='TRUE';
    END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @AI VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @EM VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @AI = 'Not Provided'
    SET @EM = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    EXEC USP_SetException 
    @ExceptionDetail = @EM,
    @AdditionalInfo = @AI
    SET @TranStatus='FALSE';
    END CATCH
    SELECT @TranStatus;
```

The error am getting is

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'dealrid', table 'DB_LMS.dbo.LMS_dealerorusercreation'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: Are you really expecting anyone to go through all of that code and answer? Probably, there isn't even enough information here to answer. I also do not see any attempt on your part to solve this, and no further information. This question does not meet the lowest standards.

Comment: Side note - [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Answer (score 2):

You need  to do one of two things, either...

- ensure that you pass in a non-null value for the column, or;
- ensure that your column accepts a null value if that is a desired property of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Errors I see in the code.

While inserting into the table LMS_dealerorusercreation, you never selected dealrid column. Please select the same.

```
INSERT INTO LMS_dealerorusercreation(
rid,
stateid,
regonid,
Locid,
addres,
dealrname,
landno,
mobno,
altcontno,
email,
desig,
reporting,
status,
CompanyId,
dealrid
)
VALUES(
@rid,
@stateid,
@regonid,
@Locid,
@address,
@dealrname,
@landno,
@mobno,
@altcontno,
@email,
@desig,
@reporting,
@status,
@CompanyId,
@dealrid
)
```

Comment: dealrid is given as identity so how should i pass value to the dealrid

Answer (score 0):

it is juat as the error message states.

you are trying to do an insert to a table where dealrid has been created with not null. if you look at your insert statement, you are not selecting and passing a value to it.

Comment: dealrid has given the identity specification=true then how should i pass the values to it,it is auto incrementing

Comment: then you may not have set it to autoincrement. check the column is indeed an identity column with i.e if you script the table you should be looking for something like IDENTITY(x,y) . Try executing the following: SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘LMS_dealerorusercreation’)