# How can i update DB with associations with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have this db model:

[image]

And I'm trying to update the `GROUP` table.

This is my code:

```
using (var ctx = new TestModelContainer())
{
    ctx.GROUP.Add(new GROUP { Name = "Group 1", TEACHER = new TEACHER{FIO = "123", Email = "123@example.com"}});

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

And after line `ctx.SaveChanges()` I get an exception. What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Inner exception:
>
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FIO', table 'u399991.dbo.TEACHER'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Comment: what is the error?  Do you need to add a Person too?

Comment: @TMcKeown no. I dont need to add person. Error added to post.

Comment: you are tying to insert a null value into a column which does not allow nulls, pass a value into of the data type it was set up with it. possbile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956579/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-table-column-does-not-allow-nulls

Answer (score 0):

By what you have provided, you can try the following:

Insert in a non-null value for the column, or you can ensure that your column accepts a null value.